# Are these two conditions always equivalent for the lattice $\mathbb Z^d$ for any property (P)?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, euclidean-geometry, integer-lattices

Consider the lattice $\mathbb Z^d$ in $\mathbb R^d$ and the following two statements:

Let $(P)$ be a property on vectors in $\mathbb R^d$ and let $1\le k \le d$.

> (1) For any $k$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, ... , v_k$ in $\mathbb Z^d$, there exists $v_i$ ($1 \le i \le k$) satisfying the property (P).

> (2) For any rank-$k$ subgroup $L$ of $\mathbb Z^d$, there exists a nonzero vector $v$ in $L$ satisfying the property (P) that can be extended to a basis of $L$.

I wonder if they are equivalent. Clearly (1) implies (2) for any property (P). But does (2) imply (1)? Can anyone prove it or show there is a property (P) such that this may not happen?

Comment: This is hard to follow, in particular property $(1)$.  What's $k$?  Can I take $k=1$?  If so, that would seem to mean that *every* non-zero vector has property $P$. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @lulu Yes. I removed some confusing words...

Comment: @lulu when k=1 they are equivalent trivially.

Comment: So...every non-zero vector has property $P$?  That's not a very interesting property.

Comment: I think the question is: "is it true for all properties $P$ and all natural numbers $k$ that (1) holds if and only if (2) holds?"

Comment: @lulu I am asking about the equivalence of 1 and 2. Property P also appears in 2. This is rather a logic question. Can you find a property P that make one holds but the other fail?

Comment: @lulu's concern is that you have not explained the quantification on $k$.

Comment: The only properties that satisfy $1$ are:  "$v$ is non-zero", or "$v$ is arbitrary".  As I said, $(1)$ is not interesting.  $(2)$ is much weaker.  In a normed space, it could be "$v$ has norm $>1$", for instance.

Comment: @lulu well in your example of "norm greater than 1", (1) and (2) will both fail...if $k=1$ at least

Comment: No...$(2)$ works because we can multiply by an arbitrarily large integer.  Really, though, I think you misstated $(1)$.  As it stands, there are no non-trivial properties that satisfy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $k$, (1) implies (2):

*Proof.* Suppose (1) holds. Then let $L$ be a rank-$k$ subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Let $v_1, \dots, v_k$ be a basis for $L$. Then by (1), WLOG, $v_1$ satisfies $P$. Now $v_1$ is a nonzero vector in $L$ which satisfies $P$ and can be extended to a basis for $L$. Since $L$ was arbitrary, we conclude that (2) holds. $\square$

However, (2) does not always imply (1).

Let $d = k = 1$, and let $P(v)$ be the property "$v$ is positive".

All rank-$1$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ have a basis of the form $\{n\}$ where $n$ is a positive integer, and thus (2) holds in this case. However, not all nonzero vectors have this property, so (1) does not hold.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I have to think harder about the nature of property P in my mind...